# Using HTTPS in a Backend (Python FastAPI), Frontend (Angular) Framework

Tags: angular, heroku, https, fastapi

I have my web application with backend (Python FastAPI) and frontend (Angular) running locally. As far as I can see, I am sending http requests for login from front- to backend and the password is visible. Additionally the token comes back visible again.

Now I want to deploy everything to Heroku. Are both services deployed with a certificate in https? And if yes, shouldn't the frontend know the public key of the backend to make encrypted requests and vice versa for the response?

I am totally confused what I have to do to make the connection secure. It looks kind of fragile to me a and I cannot find the necessary information ...

Comment: If you're looking in the network tab of your browser, you will be able to see both the request and the response - the browser has access to the decrypted connection even if the connection is made over https (it would have to - after all, it's the one making the request and presenting the result). Running locally you'd usually use plain http, although you can set up a self-signed https certificate and add it to the trust store in your browser.

Comment: The browser handles the asymmetric encryption (i.e. the TLS/HTTPS part) for you; the frontend doesn't have to concern itself with that - the browser does it for you as long as you're making the request over https.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Okay, that's interesting. So the frontend makes a backend request over https and the request is automatically encrypted? But how? Where does the browser have the public key from?

Comment: https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/what-happens-in-a-tls-handshake/ - the key is signed by one of the many providers of tls certificates, these providers have their root certificates added to the popular browsers.